# radius of convergence of function that is less than a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find the power series and  radius of convergence of $f(x) = (1+x^2)sin\left(x\right)$.

I have found the power series. but for the radius of convergence can I say:
$f(x)\leq 1+x^2 \implies$ the power series of $f$ converges for any $x$

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd function and it is entire. The rad. is infinity. we just distribute mult. over addition of $(1+x^2)(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...)$

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are not answering the question. He knows the power series, he just asks whether he can deduce that $\rho=+\infty$ from the fact that $\left| f(x)\right| \le 1+x^2$.